# Animating a view when it's added / removed from the subview

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, core-animation, uiviewanimation

I want to animate a view to fade in when it's added as subview, and want it to fade out when it's removed from the superview. What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the alpha to zero before animating, then animate the alpha to one.

```
[fadingView setAlpha:0.0];
[containerView addSubview:fadingView];
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
[fadingView setAlpha:1.0];
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

Before removing the view, just animate the alpha back to zero.